# POST passing Model MVC API

Tags: .net, api, model-view-controller

Good day guys,
Im trying to send an object to an API.
and i got an error on it

```
[HttpPost]
     public async Task<object> Upsert(int Base, int SubBase,object val)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50442/");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("M01_Upsert/" + val, val);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return response.Headers.Location;

                }

            }
```

and here is the API function im calling

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void M01_Upsert(object val)
        {
            var data = val;
        }
```

How do i call this properly?. Am i doing it correctly?. It gives me a error on method to call.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, you are not serializing your [object val] correctly

Comment: @ShaiAharoni.. it gives me a 404 error...

Comment: @ShaiAharoni..should i call it "M01_Upsert?Val=Object" ...

Comment: @ShaiAharoni or how do i deserialize it?.. whats the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the [val] that you add to the post URL.

So change the following code line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("M01_Upsert/" + val, val);
```

To:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("M01_Upsert", val);
```

On POST requests the payload should not be a part of the URL parameters. You pass it as a parameter to the `PostAsJsonAsync` method.

Comment: What if call a multiple parameter?... like this public void M01_Upsert(int x, int y,object int)

Comment: @JesunBicar, you can either: 1.Add a and y as query parameters (eg : ?x=1&y=2) which I don't think is recommanded. Or you can add x and y as properties to you val object